# Table line color

Tags: tables, color

So, in my table I've have even/odd row color, and the text color of those are resp. the complementary colors for slightly increased visibility/contrast. I've achieved this with somebody's code from the SE, has to do with transferring the commands for colors from cell to cell so they don't reset every time. However, the lines of the table get drawn after the text or before, I dunno, but the 'wrong' color is used, to demonstrate- [image] (with black and white the table's lines somehow disappear, or it's blank on blank and white on white, even though only color definitions change.

I'll supply the necessary snippets, since it's a .sty that's a mess, if somebody want the whole shabang, I'll bear the great shame of awful code.

```
    % APPLYING TEXT COLOR FROM CELL TO CELL WITHIN ROW
    \makeatletter

    \newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}

    \newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
    \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
    \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
    }

    \newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
    >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
    }

    \newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
    >{\@rowstyle}%
    }

    \makeatother
```

The colors are used thusly:

```
\newcommand*{\QQ}[8][&]{%
    \ifblank{#8}%
        {\stepcounter{row}\stepcounter{mrow}}%
        {% REMARKS NOT BLANK
            \setbox1=\hbox{\noindent#8}% fixme
            \pgfmathparse{int(ceil(divide(\wd1,312.4)))}% mcolumn of 11cm width=312.4pt; division by 1
            \ifstrequal{#1}{&}%
                {\addtocounter{row}{\pgfmathresult}\addtocounter{mrow}{\pgfmathresult}}%
                {\addtocounter{row}{\pgfmathresult}\stepcounter{mrow}}%
        }%
    \ifblank{#3}{}{\addtostream{data}{\theyear-%
        \ifnumcomp{\value{month}}{<}{10}{0\themonth-}{\themonth-}\ifnumcomp{\value{day}}{<}{10}{0\theday}{\theday} #2, #3}}% 
    \ifbool{rc}%
        {\rowstyle{\color{evenRowTextColor}}\global\boolfalse{rc}}%
        {\rowstyle{\color{oddRowTextColor}}\global\booltrue{rc}}%
    \ifbool{rcc}%
        {\cellcolor{oddRowColor}}%
        {\cellcolor{evenRowColor}}%
    #1%  date
    #2&% time
    #3&% blood glucose
    #4&% insulin
    #5&% carbohydrates
    #6&% protein
    #7&% fat
    #8%  remarks
    \\%
    }
```

the colors used:

```
% odd/light row and text color
\definecolor{oddRowColor}{RGB}{55,25,31}

\colorlet{oddRowTextColor}{-oddRowColor}

 % even/dark row and text color
\definecolor{evenRowColor}{RGB}{29,17,21}

\colorlet{evenRowTextColor}{-evenRowColor}

\colorlet{tc0}{green!65}

\definecolor{pageBG}{HSB}{47,22,26}

\DeclareCaptionFont{cc}{\color{white}}
\captionsetup{font+={cc}}

\pagecolor{pageBG}
\color{tc0}% first row color and then gets lost
```

Is there any simple way of getting the color of the table lines to show up in a tc0, in this case? Like, enclosing the relevant separators `{\color{tc0} &}`, or?

Answer (score 1):

Placing a `\color{tc0}` after the last arg, `#8`, but before the `\\` was enough to color table lines. Guess that what a whole lotta writing for nothing much in the end.

Bonus- after fiddling I found out that to get fancyhdr header/foots colors to register you gotta change the color before start of the documents, whereas most everything else you can change inside, say, you can change the color of the text, but that doesn't change ruler color (which could be possible in some other way, who knows, not me).